# Generating a user-generated number of turtle objects using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, turtle-graphics

My professor has asked me to generate a user-defined number of turtle objects using list comprehension and I can't figure out how this would be done.

```
import math
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-300,-400,300,400)

wn.bgcolor('white')
num_of_turts = int(input("Enter the number of turtles to use: "))
turts = [turtle.Turtle() for t in range(num_of_turts)]:

wn.exitonclick()
```

This is a start, but I get an invalid syntax error because of 'turtle.Turtle()'

Any ideas?

Specs:

```
1.  Create a display area with coordinates in the range of a rectangle bounded by opposite diagonal corners at (-300, -400) and (300, 400).
2.  From user input, determine a number n of turtles to create.
3.  Use a list comprehension to create a list of n turtles
4.  With and for the bale of turtles:
    a.  Begin each turtle moving randomly within the display area. 
    b.  The turtles may be colored and color other than red or green. 
    c.  There must be a function to calculate a turtle’s next location. 
    d.  All turtles must remain in the display area.
5.  Create a red turtle and make its position match the average location of the other n turtles.
    a.  There must be a function to calculate and return the average location of the n turtles.
    b.  The red turtle must leave a pen trail
6.  Create a green turtle and make its position track exactly one of the current leftmost, rightmost, uppermost or bottommost turtle in the display. 
    a.  There must be a function to calculate and return the proper coordinate of the current, extreme-most turtle.
    b.  The green turtle must leave a pen trail.
    c.  Use the green turtle to draw a line the complete width or height of the display area at each extreme value of turtle location found for the bale. Use a horizontal line if tracking upper- or lower-most. Use a vertical line, if tracking left- or rightmost
```

Comment: What's the exact error? `turtle.Turtle()` isn't a syntax error.

Comment: I added an extra colon at the end.

Comment: In the future, don't say "I get an invalid syntax error because of 'turtle.Turtle()'" unless you actually know that `turtle.Turtle()` is the part of the line causing the error. (And, if it isn't obvious how you know, include that in the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a colon at the end of the line:

```
turts = [turtle.Turtle() for t in range(num_of_turts)]:
```

That's invalid in Python. It should be:

```
turts = [turtle.Turtle() for t in range(num_of_turts)]
```

Other than that the syntax for the list comprehension is fine.

Comment: What would those objects be named so that I can refer to each turtle individually?

Comment: @TheLegendWhoLived: what do you mean? The above would create a list of `Turtle` objects.

Comment: So if I was to move each turtle in the list to a different location, how would I refer to them?

Comment: You can use `turts[0]`, `turts[1]`, `turts[2]` and so on to access the objects in the list. So `turts[0]` is the first object, `turts[1]` is the second object and so on.

Comment: so `turts[0].forward(100)` would move the first turtle?